# Can I provide my own variable interpolator for spring?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, apache-commons-config

I've learnt that I can provide Spring with a `<context:property-placeholder>` element, which appears to use a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to interpolate variables (i.e. replace tokens like `${foo}`) against a properties file.

Is there a way to customize the class that's used for resolving the tokens? In particular, I'd quite like to use an [Apache Commons Config](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) [`Configuration`](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration.html) object to provide the values of the tokens, rather than using a properties file.

Comment: [org.springframework.core.env.PropertyResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html) looks promising, but the javadoc doesn't really explain how to use it and it's not mentioned in the [3.1 release reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, subclass `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and override the `loadProperties` method.  This method is passed a `Properties` object which you can fill with values however you wish.  Alternatively, you can define an alternative implementation of `PropertiesPersister` and plug that into a normal `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

In Spring 3.1 you can pull values directly from your commons configuration object by creating your own `PropertySource` implementation, and registering it with the application context, typically by using an `ApplicationContextInitializer`.  [This blog post](http://scottfrederick.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/custom-property-source-in-spring-31.html) provides a good overview of the process.  `<context:property-placeholder>` in Spring 3.1 will pull values from registered `PropertySources` as well as from any properties files you specify.

Comment: And then do what with this class? Presumably I have to tell my spring configuration about it in some way.

Comment: Is there a non-`Properties` object based implementation? Commons `Configuration` interface is not a subclass of `Properties` - I may have to subclass Properties such that it wraps Configuration.

Comment: In Spring 3.1 yes, I've edited my answer with a link to a useful blog post.

Comment: Part I was very useful as I'm writing a standalone app. However it doesn't mention (though @Ian does!) that you need to add `<context:property-placeholder/>` to get it to work!